# Creating a class to call entities C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

```
    public INSERT_RESULT INSERT_NEW_RECORD(string FirstName, string LastName, string MiddleIntial )
    {
        decimal? InsertedUID;
        var nResult = new ObjectParameter("nResult", typeof(decimal));
        INSERT_RESULT insertResult = new INSERT_RESULT();

        try
        {
            using (var myDBEntities = dbEntities.GetNewEntities())
            {

                InsertedUID = myDBEntities.INSERT_LOOKUP(0, LastName, FirstName, MiddleIntial, dbEntities.global_USER_LOGGED_IN,  nResult).FirstOrDefault();


            }
            insertResult.WasInserted = true;
            insertResult.InsertedUID = InsertedUID ?? 0;
            insertResult.ExceptionText = "NONE";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            insertResult.WasInserted = false;
            insertResult.InsertedUID = 0;
            insertResult.ExceptionText = ex.InnerException.ToString();

        }

        return insertResult;
    }



public List<GET_ITEMS_Result> GET_ITEMS(decimal itemUID)
    {
        var result = new List<GET_ITEMS_Result>();
        using (var myDBEntities = dbEntities.GetNewEntities())
        {
            result = myDBEntities.GET_ITEMS(itemUID).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Above are examples of just two methods of hundreds that can be called from myDBEntities. Here is my goal. I want to create a class that will allow a person to pass in the name of the method and parameters and get back whatever return type is specified instead of having to write the above type of code over and over. Any suggestions??

Comment: WHY ARE YOUR FUNCTION NAMES IN ALL CAPS?

Comment: Could you explain this a little more what are you doing here that's more advanced than normal EF

Comment: Have you tried using reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using reflection. Check out the InvokeMethodWithParams method below.

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var instance = new AClassWithHundredsOfMethods();
      var result = InvokeMethodWithParams<AClassWithHundredsOfMethods>(instance, "INSERT_NEW_RECORD", "MyFirstName", "MyLastName", "MyMiddleInitial");
      Console.WriteLine(result);
    }


    static object InvokeMethodWithParams<T>(object instance, string methodName, params object[] parameters) where T : class
    {
      return  typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(instance, parameters);
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I get a chance I will try this. Thank you.